# No such file or directory when starting directory name with /

Tags: python

I am just confusing that when I apply:

```
os.listdir("HW-3/data_sets/")
```

It works well! and list all the name of files under that directories.However, when I added an additional slash. In my mind, it should be fine.

```
os.listdir("/HW-3/data_sets/")
```

But it shows error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/HW-3/data_sets'
```

It let me think about this program is so unstable. How can I let it work well even when user input `'/HW-3/data_sets'`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A leading slash in a path means an *absolute path*, or a path that starts at the root of your filesystem. No leading slash makes the path *relative* to your working directory (typically wherever you launched the script from).

Because of this, the initial slash results in a path that is semantically different from no leading slash, so you should not expect the script to behave the same way for those two paths.

Comment: It's important to note that this has nothing to do with Python, it's a standard thing on Unix/Linux/etc.

Comment: So does it mean in general, adding a leading slash is not allowable if it is not an absolute path?

Comment: @HaoyuChen: Yes. Adding a leading slash means a completely different path name. As John notes, this is due to how Unix/Linux handle paths.